# Como imprimir o nome da variável em C?

Tags: c, variáveis

Exemplo:

Tenho uma variável inteira chamada `menino`, como faço para imprimir em um `printf()` o nome dessa variável, ou seja `"menino"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dá para fazer com um truque no pré-processador. Achei esta macro em [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1623148/221800):

```
#define DUMP(varname) fprintf(stderr, "%s = %x", #varname, varname);
```

O segredo está no `#` que transforma o texto do código (parte do que é o código escrito) em texto literal (uma *string*) que pode ser usado pelo código. Obviamente não precisa usar o `strderr` ou mesmo o `fprintf`.

```
int i = 0;
DUMP(i); //será convertido para fprintf(stderr, "%s = %x", "i", i);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/VariableName.c).

Vejo pouca utilidade para isto em códigos normais.